# Bokeh Charts: Custom HoverTool variables for Bar Charts

Tags: plot, charts, hover, tooltip, bokeh

If I make a bar chart like this:

```
  bar = Bar(data,labels,tools='Hover')
```

I can make tooltips like this:

```
  hover = bar.select(dict(type=HoverTool))

  hover.tooltips = [
      ('Grade',' $x'),
      ('Students',' @Students'),
    ]
```

However, when I do variables with '@variable' in the tooltips, I am limited to those specified in data.  In normal Bokeh plots, I can have custom variables associated with data points by using a ColumnDataSource.  Bar does not support ColumnDataSources.  Is there another way to make custom variables available in Bokeh chart tooltips (hover)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's is an open [PR](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/2088) to add this feature to the charts interface.
It's going to be part of the next bokeh release and also be available through the dev builds (or in the master branch of course) as soon as it gets merged if you need it sooner.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The trick here is to use `GlyphRenderer` to make the bar chart aware of the data source. For e.g., you can add a line 
`bar.select(dict(type=GlyphRenderer))` **before** `hover = bar.select(dict(type=HoverTool))`. You can then refer your custom variables using `@cat`, `@zero` etc. See the following link for more information and a working example.

https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/bokeh/-aDPTqDPA3M